# Ember.js deserialize implementation

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am experimenting with the newest Ember.js api, but I have run into a slight problem. Things look and work ok, except for the route deserialize method. To perfectly understand my problem, go to my blog http://eduardmoldovan.com/, click a post, it will load. Then refresh the page. All the content would disappear. 
What am I doing wrong here? Obviously something is badly implemented, but I cannot find the problem.

Here is the rote that handles this all.

```
Ngin.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize: function(model) {
        "use strict";
        if (model) {
            return {
                channel: model.get("channel"),
                url: model.get("url") + "/"
            };  
        }

    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        "use strict";
        controller.set("channels", Ngin.Channel.find());
        controller.set("comments", Ngin.Comment.find({
                filter: "comments-by-url",
                url: model.get("url")
            })
        );
        controller.set("content", model);
    },
    model: function(parameters) {
        "use strict";
        var article = Ngin.Article.find({
                filter: "by-url",
                url: parameters.url
            });
        return article;
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        "use strict";
        this.render("header", {
            outlet: "header"
        });
        this.render("article", {
            outlet: "content"
        });
        this.render("footer", {
            outlet: "footer"
        });
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of the code here? Someone experiencing the problem in the future will not find it helpful to look into your blog and dig the code, and once you fix, nobody will have an idea of what went wrong or how it got fixed.

Comment: Sure, I will add the Route that handles this all.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here. I don't think there's enough information here to provide an answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to detail this even more.

Answer (score 2):

Deserialize is no longer part of the public API, instead you should use the `model` hook. Here's a [link to the ember guides article](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

Comment: I've read that before and tried it. Instead of deserialize, I use the model hook. Same result. It works exactly the same way. The code on the live site reflects this option.